# OSStatus error -12769?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avassetexportsession, avasset

So I've been trying to use `AVAssetExportSession` to trim a square video.  But for some reason I just keep getting this error:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo=0x1a03be70 {NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x1a04c5e0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12769.)", NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12769)}
```

From Apple's website I found out that `-11800` is an unknown error, but what about `OSStatus error -12769`?  I searched everywhere on the internet and I had not seen any question/problem related to this error code.  Please help. Thanks!

My code here:

```
AVAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:self.originalVidUrl options:nil];
AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
if (clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.width==clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height) {
    NSLog(@"Square video");
    NSArray *presets = [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:asset];
    if ([presets containsObject:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality]) {
        self.exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
        self.exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: self.tmpVidPath];
        self.exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
        CMTime start = ...
        CMTime duration = ...
        CMTimeRange range = CMTimeRangeMake(start, duration);
        self.exportSession.timeRange = range;
        [self.exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
            switch ([self.exportSession status]) {
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                    NSLog(@"%@",self.exportSession.error);
                    break;
                case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                    NSLog(@"Export canceled");
                    break;
                default:
                    NSLog(@"Export Success, File Saved.");
                    break;
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

P.S. this code works for videos taken with the native camera app (i.e. non-square/non-processed videos).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the solution, but I have no idea why or how it worked.

Simply change the preset name from `AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality` to `AVAssetExportPreset1280x720`, and you're good to go!

Comment: I need to keep the original resolution of the videos. Any idea to fix it otherwise ?